# Probability of an independent event according to past events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability

A binary communication system is used to send one of two messages:

(i) message A is sent with probability 2/3, and consists of an infinite sequence of zeroes,

(ii) message B is sent with probability 1/3, and consists of an infinite sequence of ones.

The ith received bit is “correct" (i.e., the same as the transmitted bit) with probability 3/4, and is “incorrect" (i.e., a transmitted 0 is received as a 1, and vice versa), with probability 1/4. We assume that conditioned on any specific message sent, the received bits, denoted by Y1,Y2,… are independent.

*Given that Y1,…,Y5 were all equal to 0, what is the probability that Y6 is also zero?*

For me the answer was P(Y1 = 0) = P(Y6 = 0) because as I understood the received bits are independent, but the right answer is **0.749267**.

Could you just help me to understand what I missed in the problem? :(

Comment: What do you mean by $P(Y_1) = P(Y_6) = 0$?

Comment: @Roland Sorry it was a mistake : P(Y1 = 0) = P(Y6 = 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us simplify notation, letting $X_{1-5}$ denote the event that the first five digits are all zero, and $X_6$ denote the event that the sixth digit is zero.

The question asks to find $Pr(X_6\mid X_{1-5})$, i.e. a conditional probability question asking us to find the probability that the sixth digit is zero *given that* the first five digits are all zero.

To do so, apply the definition of conditional probability:

$Pr(X_6\mid X_{1-5}) = \frac{Pr(X_{6}\cap X_{1-5})}{Pr(X_{1-5})}$

To continue, let us label a few more events.  $A$ is the event that the intended message to be sent is all zeroes, and $B$ will be the event that the intended message to be sent is all ones.  $Z_i$ will be the event that the $i^{th}$ digit is the intended digit.  Note that the problem statement tells us that each $Z_i$ is independent from $Z_j$ for each $i\neq j$.  I.e. the *correctness* of the digit is independent from digit to digit.  The *value* of the digit is most certainly not independent.

We note then that $X_6\cap X_{1-5} = \left(B\cap (Z_{1}^c\cap Z_2^c\cap\dots\cap Z_6^c)\right)\cup \left(A\cap (Z_1\cap Z_2\cap\dots\cap Z_6)\right)$

I.e. the message received has zeroes in the first six slots intentionally or unintentionally.

We continue then seeing $Pr(X_6\cap X_{1-5}) = \frac{1}{3}\cdot (\frac{1}{4})^6 + \frac{2}{3}\cdot (\frac{3}{4})^6$ and that $Pr(X_{1-5}) = \frac{1}{3}\cdot (\frac{1}{4})^5 + \frac{2}{3}\cdot (\frac{3}{4})^5$.

Completing the simplifications then, we arrive at $Pr(X_6\mid X_{1-5})=\frac{1459}{1948}\approx 0.74897$

[calculations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F3*1%2F4%5E6%2B2%2F3*%283%2F4%29%5E6%29%2F%281%2F3*1%2F4%5E5%2B2%2F3*%283%2F4%29%5E5%29)

Comment: Thank you so much @JMoravitz for the explanation, just a little thing : Message A is the sequence of 0 and Message B is the sequence of 1 (that's why your result is just a little bit different) but I definitely understand what you mean and your clear explanation! :)

Comment: @alexandresecanove whoops.  I'll fix the calculations.  I had not realized I did that.

Comment: Your explanation is so clear that I understood what you mean even with this little thing haha @JMoravitz

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that we do not know if the message $A$ or $B$ was sent. If it's A, then $P(Y_6 = 0)= 0.75$ (correct bit). If it's B, then $P(Y_6 = 0)= 0.25$.

But just calculating $P(A)*0,75 + P(B)*0,25 $ doesn't do the trick (it's roughly $0.417$), because this does not include our knowledge on the initial bits. We need to ask the question: "How likely is it that it's A given the first five bits are zero?"

Instead of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$, we need to compute the conditional probability of the message being A given that the first five bits were zeros and the conditional probability given that the first five bits were zeros, i.e. $P(A| Y_1 = Y_2 = Y_3 = Y_4 = Y_5=0)$ and $P(B| Y_1 = Y_2 = Y_3 = Y_4 = Y_5=0)$.

The problem gives us the probability for any bit being $0$ as $P(Y_i = 0 | A) = 0.75$ (if it's A, then $0$ is the correct bit) and $P(Y_i = 0|B) = 0.25$ (if it's B, then $0$ is the wrong bit).

With the help of Bayes' formula, can you complete the calculation?

The given answer $0.7492$ which is almost $0.75$ shows that it's pretty unlikely that the message is B (but it's still possible).

Comment: Thank you really much @Roland, I tried your answer before the complete one from JMoravitz to try by myself the Bayes formula :)